# @Autowired ApplicationContext vs passing an ApplicationContext object to the method

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

I have a `MyRunnalbe` implements `Runnable` and will be excuted by `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Inside this `MyRunnalbe` class, the `run()` method will call multiple `applicationContext.getBean(MyBean.class)` to get the beans I defined.

1st way of doing this is to make the `MyRunnalbe`as a `PROTOTYPE`
bean and autowire the ApplicationContext to this bean:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{    
    @Autowired    ApplicationContext m_applicationContext;

    @Overridepublic void run() {    
        MyBean myBean = m_applicationContext.getBean(MyBean.class);
        ...
    }
}
```

2nd way is to pass in an ApplicationContext from the caller instead of making the `MyRunnalbe` as a bean:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{    
    ApplicationContext m_applicationContext;

    public MyRunnable(ApplicationContext m_applicationContext) {
        m_applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Overridepublic void run() {    
        MyBean myBean = m_applicationContext.getBean(MyBean.class);
        ...
    }
}
```

So want to know which way is better? 1st or 2nd?

Comment: As `David A` said second way is better, Testability and Safety. Testability: Prevents nullPointer exception In testing and it’s easy to pass mock objects to the constructor and safety because it forces Spring to provide mandatory dependencies. We make sure that the created objects are valid after construction.

Comment: Thanks, suppose I currently have multiple `m_applicationContext.getBean` to call (to get the bean) in the `run()` method, then I should change it to passing the bean to the constructor instead? But in this way, the constructor would have too many number of parameters

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, **the second way** it the better way. And why?

The use of `@Autowired` for many developers it considered "bad practice", some explanations for that you can read here:  https://reflectoring.io/constructor-injection/

Any way, you could use [`@lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/) in order to make your code "Cleaner", example:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{    
    private final ApplicationContext m_applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void run() {    
       MyBean myBean = m_applicationContext.getBean(MyBean.class);
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am doing field autowire of ApplicationContext, not other bean here. Moreover, my actual `MyRunnable` class constructor already has 5 parameters, I don't want to add another `ApplicationContext` to my `MyRunnable` constructor